# google calender api - request to many users

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, google-calendar-api

My app should create an event in users calendar.

I have refresh token for all user I want to create a new event in their calendar.

I use NuGet package for google calendar client, but when I init google calendar client I can to init only single refresh token.

```
var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = "single token only" };
var credentials = new UserCredential(new 
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer {
            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets() {
                ClientId = "id", 
                ClientSecret = "secret"
            }
        }
    ),
    "user",
    token
);

var calenderClient = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});
```

how can I add another user refresh token?

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the api works.  You get a refresh token for each user you authenticated for that user and then you can add something to their calendar.   When you want to do the same for another user you will need to authenticate using the refresh token for that user and then add the event.

Your code looks good just loop it for each refresh token.